# Load previous state of dynamically created component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, utility-bar, create-component

How do I load the previous state of the lightning component that is dynamically created which is embedded inside another lightning component in the Utility bar.

Component in Utility Bar: SampleCreator.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**SampleCreatorController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var utilityBarAPI = component.find("utilitybar");
        var utilityItemLabel = "Sample Form";
        utilityBarAPI.getAllUtilityInfo().then(function(response){
            if(typeof response !== 'undefined'){
                var utilityId = '';
                for(var i=0; i< response.length; i++){
                    var obj = response[i];
                    if(obj.utilityLabel == utilityItemLabel){
                        utilityId = obj.id;
                    }
                }
                utilityBarAPI.onUtilityClick({
                    utitlityId: utilityId,
                    eventHandler: myEventHandler
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }else{
                console.log('get All utility Info');
            }
        });
        
        var myEventHandler = function(response){
            if(response.panelVisible){
                var attributes = {};
                $A.createComponent("c:SampleForm",attributes,function(comp, status, errorMessage){
                    if(status === "SUCCESS"){
                        component.set("v.body",comp);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    },
})
```

SampleForm.cmp is the component that is dynamically getting created

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="pageOne" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="FName" type="string" default="Hello"/>
    <aura:attribute name="LName" type="string" default="There"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.pageOne}">
        <div>
        <lightning:input label="First Name"
                         name="expensename"
                         value="{!v.FName}"
                         required="true"/>
        <lightning:input label="Last Name"
                         name="expensename"
                         value="{!v.LName}"
                         required="true"/>
          <br />
          <lightning:button variant="base" label="Next" onclick="{! c.handleNext }"/>
    </div>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <div>
                <p>First Name: {!v.FName}</p>
                <p>Last Name: {!v.LName}</p>
                <br />
                <lightning:button variant="base" label="Previous" onclick="{! c.handlePrevious }"/>
            </div>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
    
</aura:component>
```

**Screenshots**
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL1iK.png)

[image]

**PROBLEM**

When I minimize utility item while on Page Two and then reopen it, I want to start the component where it was left (Page Two) but it is going back to Page One because of CreateComponent. Is there a way I can get the component session and load to v.body?

**UPDATED INFO**

Apologies, I should've included this in the problem description that in the actual use case SampleForm.cmp is a OmniStudio OmniScript (https://www.apexhours.com/introduction-to-omniscripts/). Restart OmniScript functionality is not working If there are child OmniScripts within it. Which is why we ended up with the dynamic creation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `aura:attribute` of type `Map` on the Parent component to store the previous state values.

In your case, you will use `aura:attribute` on the **SampleCreator.cmp** to store those previous values.

Example code

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
<aura:attribute name="previousState" type="Map" default="{ FirstName: '', LastName: '' }" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

{!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

You can then on child save, pass these values as events, and store them on the Parent Component.

Comment: I updated my question now that another problem is SampleForm is a Omnistudio Omniscript which is why I was looking for If there's a way to retrieve the component state from cache?